# Volume of $M = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3 : z^2 \le x^2 + y^2 \le r^2, z \ge 0\}$

Tags: integration, volume

I am having a hard time solving this. Is $M$ 2D or 3D? Isn't it an infinite cylinder which starts at the $x,y$ axis and grows vertically with $z$? Or is it just a circular disk at $x,y$ axis?

We are supposed to calculate this with Cavalieri's principle...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to integrate $\int_{0}^{r} \int_{z}^{r} \int_{0}^{2\pi} s\; d\phi\; ds\; dz$. Why?

Geometrically, you get a cylinder of radius $r$ and height $r$ with a hollowed out inverted cone. So you can also readily do this with Cavalieri's Priniple.

So, $Vol(M) = Vol(cylinder) - Vol(cone) = \pi r^2h (1 - 1/3) = \frac{2\pi r^2h}{3}$. Now, $h=r$ and so $Vol(M)=\frac{2\pi r^3}{3}$. I refer use to [Wiki on Cavalieri's Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle) for more details; there is a similar problem with a sphere.

Comment: @blondy, does this help? Or are you looking for something else?

Comment: so the result is $2*pi*r^3/3$? Isn't this the volume of a half-sphere? And how exacty can I use Cavalieri efficiently here?

Comment: @blondy: Firstly, the volume of the sphere is $4\pi r^3/3$. As for using Cavalieri, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: but I don't get it, if we get the volume of a half-sphere then how is M a cylinder with a cone piece missing?

Comment: @blondy: No spheres are needed. Think about the region $M$ in cylindrical coordinates and everything will become clear. If it helps, try sketching the region. Note that rotating the region about the z-axis doesn't change it; that is it is azimuthally symmetric.